# duplicate unsorted linked list

Tags: linked-list, duplicates, hashtable

I've found this function to remove duplicate values in linked list:

```
 public static void deleteDups (LinkedListNode n){
  Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
 LinkedListNode previous = null;
 while(n!=null){
  if(table.containsKey(n.data)){
      previous.next = n.next;
  } else {
      table.put(n.data, true);
      previous = n;
  }
  n = n.next;
}
}
```

Why is better copy the element in an hash table and not to another structure like a different linked list?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because checking for the existence of an item is an `O(N)` operation in a linked-list, however it is `O(1)` for the hash-table. Performance is the reason.

```
if(table.containsKey(n.data))
```

this is where the current item is checked if it is seen before (a duplicate) and that operation would be costly when implemented via a linked-list.